# How to prevent javascript/jquery execution on specific HTML element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the possibility of the $subject?

Just imagine I have a `foo` html element

e.g.

```
<div data-toggle="loader">...</div>
```

and have a jquery function binded to it by default,

e.g.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle=loader]').loader();
});
```

So this will change the DOM element to something like,

e.g.

```
<div data-toggle="loader" class="active" style="height:800px">...</div>
```

---

So what I want to do is prevent applying the changes to the `foo` element, if it has a class name `.example`. So the catch is, I cannot touch the default execution code. But I can write another function to handle it. That is the problem I'm facing right now. Any possibility of achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest would be to either change the DOM structure, i.e. so the JS no longer finds the element, or overwrite the jQuery plugin with something innocuous. Do this in a script after the plugin script itself has loaded.

```
jQuery.fn.loader = jQuery.noop; //$.noop is an empty, pointless function
```

[EDIT]

In light of the OP's comment, the best bet may be to store a clone of the element then replace the original element with it after the plugin has fired.

```
var
el = $('.some-element'),
clone = el.clone(1, 1);
//some time passes... plugin is called... does nothing to element
el.replaceWith(clone);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. But it will disable everywhere in the page right? I want to keep it apply for others elements except the elements with `.example` class. Because page can contains many other function as well.